# How to get mule security context or security principal reference in mule flow

Tags: mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio

Was trying out authentication and authorisation in mule and got it working. Now I want the reference to the mule security context specifically the **principal** object reference to be used within the flow . How to get hold of the reference to principal object in mule inside a flow?

link to [**mule xml**](https://github.com/mule-examples/tutorial/blob/master/src/main/app/tutorial.xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security context is available through MuleSession and this session is available through eventContext. To get eventContext reference, following can be done.

This can be achieved by implementing Callable. Create the following java class. Now place a java component in the mule flow where this has to be invoked and configure with the created java class. Mule calls automatically onCall method which has eventContext as a parameter and no extra configuration is required to invoke.

The example java component gets the security content from session and from that it gets the security principal and stores it in a flow variable "user" which can be used by other flow elements which appear after this java component in the flow.

```java
import org.mule.api.MuleEventContext;
import org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable;
import org.mule.api.security.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

public class GetSecurityPrincipalCallable implements Callable {

@Override
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
    Authentication auth = eventContext.getSession().getSecurityContext()
            .getAuthentication();
    UserDetails principal = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
    System.out.println("username is : " + principal.getUsername());
    eventContext.getMessage().setInvocationProperty("user", principal);
    return null;
  }

}
```

Comment: I've been searching for this for hours! This did the trick. Thank you so much! :-)